Angular tests with Jest: How to inject HttpClient: Can't resolve all parameters for xxxx
I'm moving my tests from jasmine/karma to Jest.
I'm struggling to inject HttpClient and its testing controller.
I'm following https://angular.io/guide/http-test-requests  and I get this dummy test:
import { HttpClient, provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpTestingController, provideHttpClientTesting } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

describe('Testings tests', () => {
  let httpTestingController!: HttpTestingController;
  let dummyTest: DummyTest;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [DummyTest, provideHttpClient(), provideHttpClientTesting()],
    });
    httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
    dummyTest = TestBed.inject(DummyTest);
  });

  fit('Should request data', async () => {
    const promise = dummyTest.TestRequest();

    httpTestingController.expectOne('https://google.com').flush({});

    await promise;
  });
});

export class DummyTest {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  async TestRequest() {
    await this.httpClient.get('https://google.com');
  }
}

but when I do run it, I get an error:
NG0204: Can't resolve all parameters for DummyTest: (?).

  10 |       providers: [DummyTest, provideHttpClient(), provideHttpClientTesting()],
  11 |     });
> 12 |     httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
     |                                     ^
  13 |     dummyTest = TestBed.inject(DummyTest);
  14 |   });

I'm not sure what I'm missing out, because the HttpClient and the HttpClientTesting is provided.
I'm using angular 18 and latest version of jest.

Try add the decorator for service. The providedIn root might be optional.
When working with observables you can just subscribe to them. Then use fakeAsync and flush from angular testing, to wait for the subscribe to complete.
Updated my answer, based on Angular Testing Docs
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class DummyTest {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  TestRequest() {
    return this.httpClient.get('https://google.com');
  }
}

describe('Testings tests', () => {
  let httpTestingController!: HttpTestingController;
  let dummyTest: DummyTest;
  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [DummyTest, provideHttpClient(), provideHttpClientTesting()],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  fit('Should request data', () => {
    httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
    dummyTest = TestBed.inject(DummyTest);
    const config$ = dummyTest.TestRequest();
    // `firstValueFrom` subscribes to the `Observable`, which makes the HTTP request,
    // and creates a `Promise` of the response.
    const reqPromise = firstValueFrom(config$);
    // At this point, the request is pending, and we can assert it was made
    // via the `HttpTestingController`:
     const req = httpTestingController.expectOne('https://google.com');
    // We can assert various properties of the request if desired.
    expect(req.request.method).toBe('GET');
    // Flushing the request causes it to complete, delivering the result.
    req.flush({});
    // We can then assert that the response was successfully delivered by the `ConfigService`:
    expect(await reqPromise).toEqual({});
    // Finally, we can assert that no other requests were made.
    httpTesting.verify();
  });
});


Adding the @Injectable removes the error. But then I get an error indicating that the expected request has not been called. I tried with fakeAsync/flush(not exactly like your code, because "TestRequest" has to be async(and is not an observable), but it doesn' help

@J4N updated my answer! with reference to the official docs

Thanks, but firstValueFrom only work on Observable, my tested method(TestRequest) has to be async(in my real case).
If I just await on the result of TestRequest, it still has the error.
Your solution also doesn't compile, because configPromise doesn't exists.
Here is my current status, which still has the issue that it consider google has not been requested: https://codefile.io/f/uobrU7loqV

@J4N THe httpclient get method returns a observable, so I got confused, but I changed the code to skip the conversion to promise and execute the call directly, do check it

Damned, you're correct, my dummy tests was a bit wrong, I had to add a lastValueFrom to have something that represent a bit more my real test, and now it's working.

@J4N I reverted my answer to the original code, hope it matches the solution
